# how to specify privacy settings( public , friends or only me) in Android Native Facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook, privacy

I am searching for a long time and i was not successful yet .

Is there any method to specify the privacy setting while logging into the facebook itself through native login , so that whatever activities i do on facebook through app , posts in facebook with the specified privacy settings .

i am following the below link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/ for setting up the facebook native login .

while searching i found some codes for ios , they have something like

- FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
- FBSessionDefaultAudienceALL_FRIENDS
- FBSessionDefaultAudienceSELF

for privacy settings . But is there anything for android ?

i have added my code ,

```
public class SplashFragment extends Fragment
{
    LoginButton authButton;
    //private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("user_photos","email","user_status","friends_status","user_videos","user_checkins","friends_checkins","offline_access","user_actions.news","user_actions:parii_apps","user_events","friends_events");
    //private static final List<String> PERMISSION = Arrays.asList("publish_actions","publish_stream","publish_checkins","manage_pages","create_event","rsvp_event");

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);

        authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_logIn_btn);
        authButton.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.ONLY_ME);
        Log.e(" setDefaultAudience ", " is "+authButton.getDefaultAudience());

        return view;
    }


}
```

this is not working for me

Any related answers are welcomed . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Default audience only comes into play when you request for publish permissions, which you need to do through a session.requestForNewPublishPermissions() call with a NewPermissionsRequest object.

You can set a default audience on the NewPermissionsRequest object, see the javadocs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session.NewPermissionsRequest

Comment: i went through the code but i could not get it clear . i added this line to LoginButton , LoginButton authButton.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.ONLY_ME);   But this does not do anything . Could you please explain briefly .

Comment: What permissions are you asking for? Default audience only applies to "publish" permissions like publish_stream, publish_actions, etc. Otherwise it's a no-op.

Comment: i want to set the privacy mode for the posts i do from my application . (i.e) If i specify ONLY_ME , then that particular post must me visible only to me and if EVERYONE , then the post must be shared as public ( visible to all ) . . . .

Comment: Please post the code on how you're doing this. I think we're speaking over each other at this point.

Comment: i have added the code to the question , please review it above .

Comment: Setting the default audience does not work globally, it only works for the particular permissions request you're making. So when you're asking for the [publish_actions, ...] permissions, that's when you need to set the default audience. Setting it just on the auth button doesn't do anything since that's not when you're asking for the publish permissions.